# Make an array of names and if the names are the same add a number at the end of the name - version 2

Tags: c++

I'm writing something like the Unity's shader graph and I'm kinda stuck on a property panel.

I add a float property, which name is `Float`, and then I add a second float property, which also is named `Float` (until I rename it). I'd like the second property name to be renamed to `Float(1)`

What I tried at the beginning was a simple `vector` of properties:

> ```
> struct Property
> {
>     Property(std::string_view name, std::any value)
>         : name(name), value(std::move(value)) {}
>
>     std::string name;
>     std::any value;
> };
>
> template<typename PropertyT>
> void Add(std::string_view name, PropertyT&& value)
> {
>     static uint32_t counter = 0;
>     auto finalName = counter == 0 ? name : fmt::format("{}({})", name, counter);
>     properties.emplace_back(finalName, std::move(value));
>     ++counter;
> }
>
> void Remove(std::string_view name)
> {
>     std::erase_if(properties, [name](const auto& prop){ return prop.name == name; });
> }
>
> std::vector<Property> properties;
> ```

But the `static uint32_t counter` is not a valid solution, because

1. it's a static variable
2. the counter is never decremented, so if `Float(1)` is removed, then the next float property will be `Float(2)`, but it should be `Float(1)`.

So I thought I'd do a map of the property pool by name.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <functional>

struct Property
{
    Property(std::string_view name, std::any value, size_t index)
        : name(name), value(std::move(value))
    {
        if (index != 0) {
            this->name += "(" + std::to_string(index) + ")";
        }
    }

    const bool isValid() const
    {
        return value.has_value() && !name.empty();
    }

    std::any value;
    std::string name;
private:
    friend struct PropertyPool;

    int64_t next = 0;
};

struct PropertyPool
{
    [[nodiscard]] inline size_t Add(std::string_view name, std::any&& value)
    {
        if (nextFree != -1) {
            const size_t index = (size_t)nextFree;
            nextFree = pool[nextFree].next;
            auto& prop = pool[index];
            prop = Property(name, std::move(value), index);
            nameToId[prop.name] = index;
            return index;
        } else {
            const size_t index = pool.size();
            auto& prop = pool.emplace_back(name, std::move(value), index);
            nameToId[prop.name] = index;
            return index;
        }
    }

    void Remove(size_t index)
    {
        auto& prop = pool[index];
        prop.name.clear();
        prop.value.reset();
        prop.next = nextFree;
        nextFree = (int64_t)index;
    }

    Property* tryGetByName(const std::string& name)
    {
        if(!nameToId.contains(name)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        const size_t index = nameToId.at(name);
        
        if(pool.size() <= index) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        if(!pool[index].isValid()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return &pool[index];
    }

    const Property* const tryGetByName(const std::string& name) const
    {
        if (!nameToId.contains(name)) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        const size_t index = nameToId.at(name);

        if (pool.size() <= index) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        if (!pool[index].isValid()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return &pool[index];
    }

    const int64_t getIDByName(const std::string& name) const {
        return nameToId.at(name);
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> nameToId;
    std::vector<Property> pool;
    int64_t nextFree = -1;
};

struct PropertySet
{
    template<typename T>
    Property& Add(std::string_view name, T&& value)
    {
        const uint32_t hash = getHash(name);
        auto& pool = pools[hash];
        size_t index = pool.Add(name, std::move(value));
        return pool.pool[index];
    }
    
    void Remove(std::string_view name)
    {
        const uint32_t hash = getHash(name);
        auto& pool = pools[hash];
        pool.Remove(pool.nameToId[std::string(name)]);
    }

    const uint32_t getHash(std::string_view name) const
    {
        auto it = name.find_last_of("(");
        if (it != std::string_view::npos) {
            name.remove_suffix(name.size() - it);
        }
        return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name);
    }

    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, PropertyPool> pools;
};

int main()
{
    PropertySet properties;
    
    properties.Add("Float", 2.0f);
    properties.Add("Float", 3.0f);
    properties.Add("Float", 0.32f);

    properties.Remove("Float(1)");

    properties.Add("Float", 0.84);
    
    return 0;
}
```

expected values:

```
Float
Float(1)
Float(2)
```

after `Remove`

```
Float
Float(2)
```

add after remove

```
Float
Float(1)
Float(2)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6K8E7Ya5f

The code looks awful, but it more or less works as I wish.

The main limitation is that this whole code is written only to support properties with the same names, that will most probably be renamed. Thus this solution is kinda useless because let's say there are 4 properties named: `Float`, `x`, `y`, `z`. The `std::unordered_map<uint32_t, PropertyPool> pools` will allocate memory, and the `PropertyPool` will also allocate memory, so it's kinda waste.

What do you think about it?
How would you implement something like this?
What would you change in my code? (I bet everything :D, but keep it for real, though)

Comment: It appears you deleted the previous version of this, despite getting an answer.  Was my answer unhelpful?

Comment: I mean it kinda was. You reverted my edit and said that I should create a new question, though. That code wasn't really working so I created a new question with a working example and a link to the compiler explorer. And yes, there are some compiler warnings I should fix, but I'm more concerned about the data structures I use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several types are missing their namespace, throughout the code: `std::size_t`, `std::int64_t`, `std::uint32_t`.  I'm guessing your compiler has exercised its privilege to also define global-namespace equivalents, but portable code can't depend on that, so properly qualify the names where you use them.

Also, consider whether you really need those exact-width types (and should therefore fail to compile on platforms that don't have them), or whether possibly-larger types would satisfy your needs - e.g. `std::int_fast64_t`.

---

We should write initialisers in the order that they will run (the order in which the fields are declared).  This constructor *looks* like it will initialise `name` before `value`, which is misleading:

> ```
> Property(std::string_view name, std::any value, size_t index)
>     : name(name), value(std::move(value))
> ```

---

> ```
> const bool isValid() const
> ```

The `const` on the return type is superfluous, as it's a value and so can be assigned to a non-const variable anyway.  Just omit that:

```
bool isValid() const
```

Similarly:

```
    const Property* tryGetByName(const std::string& name) const
```

```
    std::int64_t getIDByName(const std::string& name) const
```

```
    std::uint32_t getHash(std::string_view name) const
```

---

In `getHash()`, we have an implicit narrowing conversion, because `std::hash()` returns a `std::size_t`.  Make this explicit with a `static_cast`.  Or just use the type unchanged throughout the class.

`getHash()` doesn't use any of the object state, so it could be declared `static`.

---

I don't think it's a good idea to have so many of the data members publicly visible.  Outside code could easily break a `Property` by setting its name, or by modifying a `PropertyPool`'s `pool` vector.  I'm not convinced that `PropertyPool` class needs to be visible.

---

I don't see the value in indirecting access to `PropertyPool` through an ID number.

---

If I were writing this, I'd probably keep the name and suffix separated, and just maintain a set of suffixes used for each name, like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

```
class Property
{
    std::any value_ = {};
    std::string name_ = {};
    std::size_t suffix_ = {};

public:
    Property(std::string name, std::size_t suffix, std::any value)
        : value_{std::move(value)},
          name_{std::move(name)},
          suffix_{suffix}
    {
    }
    Property() = default;

    auto name() const
    {
        if (suffix_) {
            return name_ + '(' + std::to_string(suffix_) + ')';
        }
        return name_;
    }

    auto const& value() const
    {
        return value_;
    }

    auto& value()
    {
        return value_;
    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return value_.has_value() && !name_.empty();
    }

    friend class PropertySet;
};
```

```
class PropertySet
{
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::size_t>> suffixes_used = {};
    std::map<std::string, Property> values = {};

public:
    template<typename T>
    Property& Add(std::string name, T value)
    {
        // choose first unused suffix
        auto& suffixes = suffixes_used[name];
        auto const suffix = next_suffix(suffixes);
        auto p = Property{std::move(name), suffix, std::move(value)};
        suffixes.insert(suffix);
        return values[p.name()] = p;
    }

    void Remove(std::string name)
    {
        auto property = values.at(name);
        auto& suffixes = suffixes_used[property.name_];
        suffixes.erase(property.suffix_);
        if (suffixes.empty()) {
            suffixes_used.erase(property.name_);
        }
        values.erase(name);
    }

private:
    static std::size_t next_suffix(const std::set<std::size_t>& s)
    {
        if (s.empty()) { return 0; }
        auto predicate = [](auto a, auto b){ return a + 1 != b; };
        if (auto it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(s, predicate); it != s.end()) {
            return *it + 1;
        }
        return *s.rbegin() + 1;
    }
};
```

This eliminates the need for the `PropertyPool` class.  With a little further thought, it might be possible to remove the `friend` relation.  `friend` is often the sign of a design that can be improved.

Comment: Yep, looks much cleaner. Thank you. I didn't know about std::adjacent_find. Interesting solution. I've got to keep it in mind.

Comment: There's a lot of useful stuff in the standard library, particularly in `<algorithm>`.  It really pays to be familiar with what's there!

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I won't remember every function/algorithm from this library until I actually use/need to use it.