# Iterate over a map

Tags: c++

Referring to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/281185/266548. I'd like to iterate, every frame, over the `values`.
Do you think is a good idea to create `std::vector<Property*> values_iterator`? Or there is a better way to do it?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
class Property
{
    std::any value_ = {};
    std::string name_ = {};
    std::size_t suffix_ = {};

public:
    Property(std::string name, std::size_t suffix, std::any value)
        : value_{std::move(value)},
          name_{std::move(name)},
          suffix_{suffix}
    {
    }
    Property() = default;

    auto name() const
    {
        if (suffix_) {
            return name_ + '(' + std::to_string(suffix_) + ')';
        }
        return name_;
    }

    auto const& value() const
    {
        return value_;
    }

    auto& value()
    {
        return value_;
    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return value_.has_value() && !name_.empty();
    }

    friend class PropertySet;
};
```

````cpp
class PropertySet
{
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::size_t>> suffixes_used = {};
    std::map<std::string, Property> values = {};
    std::vector<Property*> values_iterator = {};

public:
    template<typename T>
    Property& Add(std::string name, T value)
    {
        // choose first unused suffix
        auto& suffixes = suffixes_used[name];
        auto const suffix = next_suffix(suffixes);
        auto p = Property{std::move(name), suffix, std::move(value)};
        suffixes.insert(suffix);
        auto& property = values[p.Name()] = p;
        values_iterator.push_back(&property);
        return property;
    }

    void Remove(std::string name)
    {
        auto property = values.at(name);
        auto& suffixes = suffixes_used[property.name_];
        suffixes.erase(property.suffix_);
        if (suffixes.empty()) {
            suffixes_used.erase(property.name_);
        }
        values.erase(name);
        std::erase(values_iterator, &property);
    }

    const std::vector<Property*>& getValues() const
    {
        return values_iterator;
    }

private:
    static std::size_t next_suffix(const std::set<std::size_t>& s)
    {
        if (s.empty()) { return 0; }
        auto predicate = [](auto a, auto b){ return a + 1 != b; };
        if (auto it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(s, predicate); it != s.end()) {
            return *it + 1;
        }
        return *s.rbegin() + 1;
    }
};
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `PropertySet` implementation causes ambiguity if a property has an integer `suffix` as a part of the name, e.g.

```
PropertySet ps;
ps.Add("a", 0); // a: 0
ps.Add("a", 1); // a(1): 1
ps.Add("a(1)", 2); // a(1): 2
```

The problem becomes substantial if the `PropertySet` is used together with GUI.
And I don't see any simple solution that doesn't require parsing the property name.

Also, note that we need to do something with terminating spaces, e.g. "a****" and "a" are different properties now, considering "*" as a space character.

---

As for the question, there are multiple approaches to make `PropertySet` class iterable:

- It can be thought as a `values`' [proxy class](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/proxy).
  Essentially, we have added functionality to the `map::insert` and `map::erase` methods only.
  In that sense, we can add transparent `begin` and `end` methods.
  It only depends on the degree of compatibility with STL.
- We can add a [Java-like iterator class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).